# Insert category in rss feed wordpress

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss, categories, feed

I need to insert the category of the post in the RSS feed of a WordPress Blog . I edited the file /wp-include/feed-rss.php inserting line:
    ]]> but I'm probably wrong with the php function name. So the category name doesn't appear. Can anybody help me?

http://piattoforte.tiscali.it/cibario/feed/

Answer (score 2):

I think there is default function available in wordpress the_category_rss($type). for rss the_category_rss('rss')/the_category_rss('rss2')/the_category_rss('atom') after the_title_rss() tag or wherever you want in the corresponding feed-rss.php/feed-rss2.php/feed-atom.php files in includes folder. Once this is done we can see the category tag in feed xml. Otherwise we can create add_action in functions.php

Comment: I tried to add this in the **feed-rss.php file** for example:<item>
  <title><?php the_title_rss() ?></title>
   **<!-- tried to add the call for the category -->
  <category><?php the_category_rss('rss') ?></category>**
  <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
  <link><?php the_permalink_rss() ?></link>
  <?php
  /**
   * Fires at the end of each RSS feed item. <category><![CDATA[WordPress]]></category> 
   *
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  do_action( 'rss_item' );
  ?>
 </item> but with no effect

Comment: Kindly check which php page affect the rss link, mean you rss.php or rss2.php or atom.php. Are you creating new template for the rss page or making use of default wordpress functionality